# WCF service, how to mapp the objects runtime

Tags: wcf, architecture

I have to design a wcf service which gives outut in a standard model(which i think its better to give as string/XML).But this standard model is/may be subjected to change its format.So every time its changed we need to change the code.My service should also accomadte the same with configurable change. How to do it without code change and exernal configurable entities.

Is there any way to create and mapp  the class in runtime.

My primary idea is to keep a format internally and an XML which would be the standard format and to mapp the class properties and XML nodes using a database table.

Please suggest ....Appreciate the help from GURUS !!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the question, so perhaps you could elaborate upon it, perhaps with some simplified code? However, if you need to map between XML formats, have you considered an XSL Transform?